# Plotly heatmap does not show all index values

Tags: python, plotly

Plotly go heatmap does not show all rows of a dataframe.

Here is the df
[image]

The df is created using pivot_table

```
df = result.pivot_table(index='Hour', columns='Weekday', values='Measurment', aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='Total')
```

I use this code

```
# Create a Plotly Heatmap
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=df.values,  # Use DataFrame values as the 'z' values
    x=df.columns,  # Use DataFrame columns as the 'x' values
    y=df.index,  # Use DataFrame index as the 'y' values
    hoverongaps=False
))
fig.show()
```

This result is this. Which misses two rows. Anyone, how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: I ran the code on your data. Correctly but the index was [displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZDA1.png). The version of Plotly I ran is the latest version, `5.18.0`

Comment: thx for your feedback. I have upgraded plotly and still, it does not show the rows 21 and total

Comment: Many thx!!! The colab works! Yet, i could not get my code working. The df I use, is from a pivot table. I have added the code above. Maybe plotly does not like pivot_tables. I have checked for multi-level headers, but my pivot  does not have one.

Comment: Not sure what is causing this, but specifying the y-axis index and text directly may help. Try the following; `yticks = ['14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', 'Total'];
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[yticks.index(x) for x in yticks], ticktext=yticks)` remove any comments with Colab links just in case.

Comment: ok many thx, I will try a different path